# Fetching transactions of an account result in an internal server error /v2/accounts/:account_id/transactions

Tags: coinbase-api

I receive an Internal Server Error when requesting endpoint: `/v2/accounts/xx/transactions`

First I am getting all accounts:

```
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts?limit=100
```

Then I iterate over all account ids and request the transactions. But for the following ids I get an internal server error:

**Request:**

```
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/7176ad81-fb91-5d22-9e50-7cd82030d912/transactions?limit=100&order=asc
```

**Response:**

```
500 Internal Server Error {"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
```

&

**Request:**

```
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/19ffd08f-f713-5d52-9636-ebfdcf5d6d36/transactions?limit=100&order=asc
```

**Response:**

```
500 Internal Server Error {"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
```

---

The requested account id is two times **Bitcoin**:

```
{
    id: '7176ad81-fb91-5d22-9e50-7cd82030d912',
    type: 'wallet',
    code: 'BTC',
    info: {
        id: '7176ad81-fb91-5d22-9e50-7cd82030d912',
        name: 'BTC Wallet',
        primary: true,
        type: 'wallet',
        currency: [Object],
        balance: [Object],
        created_at: '2015-11-17T13:19:13Z',
        updated_at: '2020-09-15T02:24:51Z',
        resource: 'account',
        resource_path: '/v2/accounts/7176ad81-fb91-5d22-9e50-7cd82030d912',
        allow_deposits: true,
        allow_withdrawals: true,
    },
};
```

&

```
{
    id: '19ffd08f-f713-5d52-9636-ebfdcf5d6d36',
    name: 'BTC Wallet',
    primary: true,
    type: 'wallet',
    currency: {
        code: 'BTC',
        name: 'Bitcoin',
        color: '#F7931A',
        sort_index: 100,
        exponent: 8,
        type: 'crypto',
        address_regex:
            '^([13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34})|^(bc1([qpzry9x8gf2tvdw0s3jn54khce6mua7l]{39}|[qpzry9x8gf2tvdw0s3jn54khce6mua7l]{59}))$',
        asset_id: '5b71fc48-3dd3-540c-809b-f8c94d0e68b5',
        slug: 'bitcoin',
    },
    balance: { amount: '0.00000000', currency: 'BTC' },
    created_at: '2017-09-08T17:59:20Z',
    updated_at: '2021-10-06T03:42:42Z',
    resource: 'account',
    resource_path: '/v2/accounts/19ffd08f-f713-5d52-9636-ebfdcf5d6d36',
    allow_deposits: true,
    allow_withdrawals: true,
};
```

Edit: we are now also seeing errors on:

```
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/a8263795-f4e5-55e5-92a0-bce21cef5e23/transactions?limit=100&order=asc 500 Internal Server Error {"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/26b3496c-275c-5ffd-b931-3f75e9c59a9f/transactions?limit=100&order=asc 500 Internal Server Error {"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
```

It does not error on other account ids.

Can someone from Coinbase fix this please?

Comment: "it does not error on other account IDs" that tells me the accounts are wrong. the accounts posted don't match the resource_path in your transaction.

"can someone from coinbase fix this please" coinbase doesn't come here and it probably isn't a problem on their end anyway

Comment: "that tells me the accounts are wrong" - coinbase returns those accounts in their accounts endpoint - then its a bug on their side.
"the accounts posted don't match the resource_path in your transaction" sure they do.
BTC: GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/7176ad81-fb91-5d22-9e50-7cd82030d912/transactions?limit=100&order=asc
BTC again: GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/19ffd08f-f713-5d52-9636-ebfdcf5d6d36/transactions?limit=100&order=asc

Comment: nice that they refer to Stack overflow when you hit support on their site :D

Comment: "sure they do" ... my bad, I was looking at the bottom requests. Have you tried recreating the API keys?

Comment: Those errors appear randomly across multiple user keys and account ids. So I am really out of ideas.

Comment: I am also seeing this error all the time. You cannot get a full consistent run of api calls without hitting the limit. Even with rretries of upto 10 times with delays this issue is around. Error message is not useful either.